# In core data, How to save item to their respective category parent while saving?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, parent-child

I am having two model files: Category as parent and Items as Child. If I want to save an item with parent relation, I use `UITableView` to select in which parent class it should save. But I'm unable save with category. I have given the relationship also correctly. Item is also saving but not with the relationship.

Category Model:

```
import CoreData
extension Category {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Category> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Category>(entityName: "Category")
    }
    @NSManaged public var categoryColor: String?
    @NSManaged public var categoryName: String?
    @NSManaged public var items: NSSet?
}
```

Item Model:

```
extension ItemForm {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ItemForm> {
        return NSFetchRequest<ItemForm>(entityName: "ItemForm")
    }
    @NSManaged public var itemName: String?
    @NSManaged public var price: Int64

    @NSManaged public var parent: Category?
}
```

ItemViewController:

```
var buttonIndex : Int?

@IBAction func dropDownAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if tableView.isHidden == true {
        self.tableView.isHidden = false

    }else {
        self.tableView.isHidden = true

}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        dropdownBtn.setTitle("\(arrCategory[indexPath.row].categoryName!)", for: .normal)
        animated(toogle: false)

        buttonIndex = indexPath.row

    }
      @IBAction func saveAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let selectedIndexInPopup = categoryType.title(for: .normal)

            itemSaveData()

            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    }
func itemSaveData(){

        guard let itemName = itemName.text else { return }
        guard let price = Int64(itemPrice.text!) else { return }

        guard let parentCategorty = buttonIndex else { return }

        let itemList = [
            "itemName": itemName,
            "price": price
            "parentCategory": parentCategorty

            ] as [String : Any]
         if isUpdate{
            editItemData(itemList: itemList, index: indexRow)
            isUpdate = false
        }else{
          saveItemData(itemList: itemList)
        }
}
    func saveItemData(itemList: [String:Any]){
               let item = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "ItemForm", into: context) as! ItemForm
               item.itemName = itemList["itemName"] as! String
               item.price = itemList["price"] as! Int64
         item.parent = (itemList["parentCategory"] as? Category)
    do{
                   try context.save()
                print("Save Successfully")
               }catch let err{
                   print("college save error :- \(err.localizedDescription)")
               }
           }

    }
```

How can I save this by selecting `popUpTableView` in `UIButton` in swift?

Comment: You need an instance of the Category not some index to a button, probably this: `arrCategory[indexPath.row]`

Comment: Thank you! it is saving

Comment: How to display items only  selected category related items

Comment: Use the `items` property on Category to get the items,  example `let itemsArray = Array(arrCategory[indexPath.row].items)`

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
func saveItemData(itemList: [String:Any]){
        let item = ItemForm(context: context)
        item.itemName = itemList["itemName"] as! String
        item.price = itemList["price"] as! Int64
        let parent = parent(context: context)
        //Set here your parent table value
        parent.categoryColor = "Color"
        item.parent = parent
        do{
            try context.save()
            print("Save Successfully")
        }catch let err{
            print("college save error :- \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```